# PIC16 not updating ADC values

Tags: pic, adc

Can somebody help to explain why my code or setup not updating the ADC values of a 10K-potentiometer please?

I use MPLAB XPRESS PIC16F18877 board and MPLAB MCC to generate the code. The voltage result only gets updated once after resetting the board.

main.c

```js
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"

void display_result(float v);

void main(void) {
    adc_result_t convResult = 0;
    float v = 0;

    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();

    ADCC_StartConversion(POT);


    while (1) {
        // Convert ADC values
        while (!ADCC_IsConversionDone());
        convResult = ADCC_GetConversionResult();
        v = convResult * 3.3 / 1023;

        // send the value to display
        display_result(v);
    }
}

void display_result(float v) {
    if (v > 1.65) {
        LED_SetHigh();
    } else {
        LED_SetLow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is solved by calling

```js
ADCC_StartConversion(POT);
```

in the while(1) loop.